# How to reference the output of the previous command twice in Linux command?

Tags: linux, shell, command

For instance, if I'd like to reference the output of the previous command **once**, I can use the command below:

```
ls *.txt | xargs -I % ls -l %
```

But how to reference the output twice? Like how can I implement something like:

```
ls *.txt | xargs -I % 'some command' % > %
```

PS: I know how to do it in shell script, but I just want a simpler way to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass this argument to `bash -c`:

```
ls *.txt | xargs -I % bash -c 'ls -l "$1" > "out.$1"' - %
```

Answer (score 1):

You can lookup up 'tpipe' on SO; it will also lead you to 'pee' (which is not a good search term elsewhere on the internet).  Basically, they're variants of the `tee` command which write to multiple processes instead of writing to files like the `tee` command does.

However, with Bash, you can use [Process Substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution):

```
ls *.txt | tee >(cmd1) >(cmd2)
```

This will write the input to `tee` to each of the commands `cmd1` and `cmd2`.

You can arrange to lose standard output in at least two different ways:

```
ls *.txt | tee >(cmd1) >(cmd2) >/dev/null
ls *.txt | tee >(cmd1) | cmd2
```